# install problem of lombok in eclipse neon. I tried to find it's solution. but no proper solution found

Tags: eclipse, lombok, eclipse-neon

I am getting issue in installing Lombok plugin to my Eclipse Neon IDE. 
Screenshot has been shared here.... How can I get rid of this?

It says " I can't write to your Eclipse directory, probably because this installer does not have the access rights"

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Well have you tried what that dialog box tells you to do?

Comment: @greg-449 That is what i don't know. How should I give access right to this installer.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/

Comment: @greg-449  Thank Man. It worked like a charm!!!!!!!.  What I did is go to admin cmd, changed my directory where lombok.jar is situated. and run java -jar lombok.jar  . It will work for sure!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @greg-449  said. Go to admin cmd. change directory to where your lombok.jar is situated. 
And simply run java -jar lombok.jar !!! It will work hopefully.